# Named Range Changed event not working properly

Tags: vsto

I am using VSTO to create Named range on my sheet. I register change event for all the named ranges. Now suppose i rendered 4 named ranges say A1,A2,A3,A4 on my excel sheet with values 10,20,30,40 respectively. On my cell B1,B2,B3,B4 i have values as 100,200,300,400(these are normal cells). Now if i try to copy values from B1:B4 and paste to A1:A4. The namedRange_Change event is been called 4 times. The parameter to the Changed Event is Target Range, in this case target range for all 4 changed events is coming as A1:A4. How can i identify for which cell the changed event is called? And why the Target Range is A1:A4, it should be of the respected cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target in this event handler is whole changed range. The only way I see to know which named range is changed - is to use anonymous methods. For example:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 4 ; i++) {
    NamedRange range = sheet.Controls.AddNamedRange(sheet.Cells[i, 1], "_cell" + i.ToString());
    range.Change += new DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler((Range Target) => {
        string name = ((dynamic) range.Name).Name;
        string cellAddress = Target.get_Address();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. But i am still not clear how will this work. I understood how to use anonymous methods. But here aslo the Target.get_Address will get 4 cells in cellAddress. And i have a method which listens to the change event. Will the two(name and cellAddress) become parameters for that method. Can u please explain it.

Comment: @RonakNisar You can call procedures from my anonymous method, using the name and cellAddress as parameters. Thus, the variables of my method will become parameters of your method.

Comment: I tried but it does not work.The cellAddress is still returning as A1:A4 for all the four changed events. How can i find for which cell the changed event is called.

Comment: In your example it is your NamedRange, this cell.

Comment: Thanks alex for your help. I got a help from your answer. What i was searching for is range.RefersToRange which returns me the exact range for which the event is called. Thanks a ton for your quick response.